# VBA: Why does endif shows me 0 as result when I use variable as criteria

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'd like to add a variable as criteria, but when i do it this way, excel shows me `Range("Dodawanie")=0`. If I put number instead of variable, everythings works fine.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub summer()

    Dim dod As Integer

    dod = [losowania].Value
    Dim suma As Double


    suma = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(dod + 1, 4)))
    Dim srednia As Double
    srednia = suma / dod


    Range("Dodawanie") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(dod + 1, 4)), ">srednia")
End Sub
```

Comment: The syntax for *Range* is `Range([Range name])`. *Range name* is a string. The string could be the name you gave to the range, a variable of string format containing the name or a synthetic range name which VBA concatenates from the range's coordinates, such as "A2:D2". In your code `suma = WorksheetFunction.Sum(..` must be a number, not a string, in particular since it was also declared `As Integer`. Therefore `Range("Suma")` fails. Add `Option Explicit` to your code at the top of the module.

Comment: I modified the code but still doesn't work. When I do `Range("A1")=srednia` it gives correct value, but `Range("Dodawanie")=...` no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `SumIf` Criteria Issue

- Since `srednia` is a variable, you cannot use it inside a string, but you can do this:

  ```
  ">" & srednia
  ```
- To make it more readable you can implement a range object (`rng`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub summer()

    Dim dod As Long
    dod = [losowania].Value
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(dod + 1, 4))
    
    Dim suma As Double
    suma = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
    
    Dim srednia As Double
    srednia = suma / dod

    Range("Dodawanie") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rng, ">" & srednia)

End Sub
```

To avoid some unexpected behavior, you could improve:

```
Sub summerIf()

    If IsNumeric([losowania].Value) Then ' Fails if 'losowania' contains string.
        Dim dod As Long
        dod = CLng([losowania].Value)
        If dod >= 1 Then ' Prevent division by 0 ('srednia').
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(dod + 1, 4))
            Dim suma As Double
            On Error Resume Next ' 'Sum' fails if 'rng' contains error value.
            suma = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
            If Err = False Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Dim srednia As Double
                srednia = suma / dod
                Range("Dodawanie") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rng, ">" & srednia)
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
                MsgBox "'rng' contains an error value."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "'dod' is less than 1."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "'losowania' does not contain a number."
    End If

End Sub
```